# Implement pagination using offset in java jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc, pagination, apache-drill

I am trying to implement pagination using java jdbc. My query takes the limit which is the batch size and offset.

How do i increment the offset after completion of each batch. I am unable to understand how can i use this offset to achieve the functionality. I tried to write a wrapper method which recursively calls the method which takes the offset.

Here is my query

```
select
ECId,InvId,ApplianceId,ProgName,CollectStartTS,CollectEndTS,CRPartyId,
HostName,IPAddess,SoftwareVer,OsType,collectserialnum,
CollectProductId,SNMPLoc,HWAlertCnt,SWAlertCnt,UploadProcEndTS
from inventory_details
```

and the code

```
public void getInventory() throws SQLException {
    int batch = Integer.parseInt(PropertyFileReader.getInstance()
         .getProperty("BATCHSIZE"));
    int offset= 0;
    while(offset<batch){
        DrillDAO dao = new DrillDAO();
        dao.getAllInventoryDetails(offset); 
    }   
    offset = offset+batch+1;
}

public ArrayList<InventoryDetail> getAllInventoryDetails(int offset)
             throws SQLException {              
    int batchSize = Integer.parseInt(PropertyFileReader.getInstance()
                    .getProperty("BATCHSIZE"));             

    ArrayList<InventoryDetail> inventoryDetailList = new ArrayList<InventoryDetail>();              

    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultset = null;
    try {
        Class.forName(getJdbcDriver());
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                     getJdbcURL(), getUserName(), getPassword());
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        LOGGER.info("Start time    " + CPUUtils.getCpuTime());
        resultset = statement.executeQuery(getQuery() 
                  + " " + "LIMIT" + " " + batchSize + " " 
                  + "OFFSET" + " " + offset);
        LOGGER.info("End time    " + CPUUtils.getCpuTime());

        while (resultset.next()) {
            InventoryDetail id = new InventoryDetail();
            id.setEcId(resultset.getString(1));
            id.setInvId(resultset.getString(2));
            id.setApplianceId(resultset.getString(3));
            id.setProgName(resultset.getString(4));
            id.setCollectStartTS(resultset.getString(5));
            id.setCollectEndTS(resultset.getString(6));
            id.setCrPartyId(resultset.getString(7));
            id.setHostName(resultset.getString(8));
            id.setIpAddess(resultset.getString(9));
            id.setSoftwareVer(resultset.getString(10));
            id.setOsType(resultset.getString(11));
            id.setCollectSerialNum(resultset.getString(12));
            id.setCollectProductId(resultset.getString(13));
            id.setSnmpLoc(resultset.getString(14));
            id.setHwAlertCnt(resultset.getString(15));
            id.setSwAlertCnt(resultset.getString(16));
            id.setUploadProcEndTS(resultset.getString(17));
            inventoryDetailList.add(id);
        }
    } catch (SQLException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (statement != null)
                statement.close();
        } catch (SQLException se2) {
        }
        try {
            if (connection != null)
                connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException se) {
           se.printStackTrace();
        }
    }  
    return inventoryDetailList;
}
```

Comment: Pagination is not meaningful if you don't specify some sort of ordering for the result set, i.e. declare `ORDER BY` in the query. How should the rows be ordered?

Answer (score 0):

You can write the wrapper like below:

```
public List<InventoryDetail> getInventory() throws SQLException {
        int batch = Integer.parseInt(PropertyFileReader.getInstance().getProperty("BATCHSIZE"));
        int offset= 0;

        List<InventoryDetail> finalList = new ArrayList<InventoryDetail>();

        DrillDAO dao = new DrillDAO();
        for(int i = offset; ; i += batch+1) {
            //request data with one more, if exact that count return, you will know more data exist
            //so you can continue; when less than that return, you will know no more data, so break the loop
            ArrayList<InventoryDetail> invList = dao.getAllInventoryDetails(i, batch + 1);            
            if (invList.size() <= batch) {                
                break;
            } else {
                //remove the extra one called cz it will get in next call
                invList.remove(invList.size() - 1);                
            }
            finalList.addAll(invList);
        }

        return finalList;
    }
```

Change

```
public ArrayList<InventoryDetail> getAllInventoryDetails(int offset)
            throws SQLException {
```

to

```
public ArrayList<InventoryDetail> getAllInventoryDetails(int offset, int batchSize)
            throws SQLException {
```

and remove the the following line inside it.

```
int batchSize = Integer.parseInt(PropertyFileReader.getInstance()
                    .getProperty("BATCHSIZE"));
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to get the count of your SELECT:

```
String countQuery = "SELECT COUNT(0)\n" +
    "FROM INVENTORY_DETAILS";
```

Now that you have your result size, ask if it is greater than 0, this way you wont have to execute the original query for nothing:

```
// here goes the statement declaration and execution
long count = statement.execute(countQuery);
List<InventoryDetail> inventoryDetailList = new ArrayList<InventoryDetail>();

if (count > 0) {
    String query = "SELECT ECID,INVID,APPLIANCEID,PROGNAME,COLLECTSTARTTS,COLLECTENDTS,CRPARTYID,\n" +
        "    HOSTNAME,IPADDESS,SOFTWAREVER,OSTYPE,COLLECTSERIALNUM,\n" +
        "    COLLECTPRODUCTID,SNMPLOC,HWALERTCNT,SWALERTCNT,UPLOADPROCENDTS\n"+
        "FROM INVENTORY_DETAILS\n";
```

Finally, and this is the most important part of the instruction, you will iterate over your pagination:

```
    long page = 1;
    long limit = page * offset;
    long loops = (count - (count % limit)) / offset;

    for (; page <= loops; page++) {
        if (page == 1) {
            query += "LIMIT " + limit;
        } else {
            limit = page * offset;
            query += "LIMIT " + limit + " OFFSET " + offset;
        }

        // here goes the statement declaration and execution
        statement.execute(query);
        // here goes the result set iteration and then...
        inventoryDetailList.add(id);
    }
}
```

Hope it help.

Comment: Because no row-ordering is specified in the query, nothing guarantees that the same row doesn't appear on more than one page.

Comment: Yeah I know, but that king of implementation requires more explanation and more complexity to add because it needs paginate dynamically depending on some field added to the row-ordering. My intention here was just give a hint to how to implement a simple pagination. Anyone can check this [implementation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/database/support/SqlWindowingPagingQueryProvider.java) from the Spring Project that explains my previous comment.